# Why is the SR behavior of mass and a clock different?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

A frame contains a mass and a clock, an an adjacent frame contains an identical mass and clock. One frame travels and returns.

The special relativity equations for mass and time are identical in form.

On return the two masses are seen to have the same magnitude, but the two clocks show different magnitudes.

Why do mass and time not behave the same way given their equations are the same?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What would you *expect* the mass to do?

Comment: In a modern treatment "the mass" doesn't change because it always means rest mass. We have stopped using "relativistic mass" a long time ago. The theoretically better concept to use is the four-momentum, which has the total energy as its zeroth component.

Comment: Time is a coordinate, on the relativistic view, but mass is not a coordinate, it is a property so the "equations for mass and time" cannot be identical in form.

Comment: As to same "form" I should have written m' = gamma * m_r and t' = gamma * t

Comment: Both experience the same gamma, why is one changed and one not? Thanks, I'll read about four-momentum. But still looking for a model to help me see what ever it is I don't understand.

Comment: Coordinate/property: If I add a ruler to each frame (a coordinate) it will be unchanged like the mass (a property) and not like the clock (a coordinate).

Comment: OK Four-momentum got it. Though perhaps space-time 4-vector seems closer to my question. I suspect the answer to my question may be the minus in the scalar product of  these 4-vectors; this differs from the ordinary scalar product of vectors.  Is this the right track? If so what property of time, but not mass or length, is encoded in the minus? Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do mass and time not behave the same way given their equations are the same?

As indicated, relativistic mass is a concept that was abandoned long ago as misguided. You can't just take Newtonian equations and replace mass with gamma times the rest mass and get correct physics. The problem is that Newtonian physics has multiple equations that are equivalent in Newtonian physics but not equivalent in relativistic  physics, so there is no way to save them all. Two things that aren't equivalent can't be made equivalent just because you don't want to learn the correct equations.

Instead of using $$\sum_i \vec F_i=m\vec a,$$ use $$\sum_i \vec F_i=\frac{\mathrm d \vec p}{\mathrm d t}$$ instead, they are no longer equivalent so you have to pick one.

So what kinds of things still hold? Mass still tells you how energy and momentum balance but instead of $E=\frac{\vec p^2}{2m}$ you use $E=\sqrt{\vec p^2c^2+(mc^2)^2}.$ And instead of $\vec p=m\vec v$ you use $\vec p=E\vec v/c^2.$ And mass is a constant, it's the energy in the rest frame divided by $c^2$ or it's $m=\frac{1}{c^2}\sqrt{E^2-\vec p^2c^2}.$ And it doesn't change in time, and the mass of a system is **not** the sum of the masses of the parts. And finally, mass isn't the source of gravity. All it is is a constant telling how much additional energy you have than $\sqrt{\vec p^2c^2}$ and it doesn't simply add, it appears as $m=\frac{1}{c^2}\sqrt{E^2-\vec p^2c^2}.$

So how about time. Time comes up in two places. One is as a coordinate label, you have to specify a time and a place to fully specify the event. The second is a duration.

As a duration it turns out that a clock does *not* have a magical way to read the coordinate. Just like when you measure with a measuring tape, the path of the tape matters. So with a clock.

A clock moves in a 4 dimensional spacetime. And like a measuring tape it leaves a tick at places along its path. Each tick has an equally spaced path, if only we know how clocks measure paths in spacetime.

And the answer is that for two events close together a clock measures $$\sqrt{(c\Delta t)^2)-(\Delta x)^2-(\Delta y)^2-(\Delta z)^2}$$ and when it finally gets a light second of distance according to that measure, the second hand ticks.

And that is what clocks measure. And that's life. They measure duration along paths. And that's all. You don't have direct access to coordinates because clocks and rulers just do what they do, and don't have the ability to act other than how they act. A clock at rest is measuring changes in time, $\Delta t,$ but in general a clock measures $$\sqrt{(c\Delta t)^2)-(\Delta x)^2-(\Delta y)^2-(\Delta z)^2}.$$

Comment: Much detail to absorb here, thank you. So the key point about life (if I get it) is that clocks use the positive root, thus increment and never decrement. [would it be clearer to say time is the positive root?].

Comment: @JackThreadfin Energy uses the positive root too. But like WillO argues, the energy at the end of your journey depends on your speed at the end of your journey. And the **rate** your clock is ticking at the end of your journey depends on your speed at the end of your journey too. But the **reading** on the clock depends on the path. His example is a better story for how gravity affects clocks. The path matters, and for gravity where it goes matters too.

Comment: Could you point me to a good text book, something about the level of your description? [The area I want to understand is rotational change under relativistic rectilinear change.]

Comment: @JackThreadfin Taylor and Wheeler's Spacetime Physics is at about the level I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

You and I are I identical twins, living on the fourth floor of a building, each eating one cupcake per minute.

Now you spend an hour on the eighth floor, eating two cupcakes per minute, and then return to the fourth floor.

During that hour, the equation relating our altitudes and the equation relating our cupcake consumption have the same form.  (Each is $y=2x$, where $x$ is my height or watch-rate and $y$ is yours.)

But even though those equations have the same form, upon your return, our altitudes are the same but our weights are different.  I hope you don't find that baffling.

Likewise, if your (relativistic) mass doubles for an hour, and the rate at which your wristwatch ticks also doubles for an hour (both, in this case, as measured by me), then at the end of the hour, when your mass and your watch-rate both return to "normal", your mass is --- well, back to normal, but the time on your clock is not.

Comment: I enjoyed this answer. If I understand, to paraphrase, there is an 'arrow of time' but not an 'arrow of cupcakes'.